# Centering equation on a line

Tags: math-mode, equations

I am trying to center my equation on the line using this code:

```
\[

\ l_{12} =  \frac {m_{c} c_{c} \frac {dT_{c}}{dt} + m_{s} c_{s} \frac {dT_{s}}{dt}}{m_{s}} Delta t 

\]
```

but I keep getting this error: `Missing $ inserted.`
I tried adding $ but it's still not working.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Are there empty lines in your source, too? (Comment those lines out (`%`) or remove them. This applies to every math mode (plain, LaTeX or `amsmath`s environment).)

Comment: I can confirm that it works when removing empty lines.

Comment: I removed the empty lines but I am getting the same error. Is there a specific package I need to use? I have now {amsmath} and {amssymb}

Comment: @Lynn Can you post a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`? A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: It worked when I indented the lines by 4 spaces. Thanks a lot!

Comment: It worked for me when I removed the blank lines, as @ketan said. I've encountered this nuisance before. It did not work for me when I indented four spaces. Please check your solution. Then you can answer your own question, with whatever worked.

Comment: Yep, as the others said you have a blank line issue. Also, there is a leading backslash that I think was meant for `\Delta` instead which is missing the backslash.  The four space indenting is only for posting here so that the code gets displayed as code rather than text.

Answer (score 1):

As already said in my comment. Empty lines in math mode are not allowed.

Comment them out with `%` or remove them entirely.

If you load [`amsmath`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) you have the benefit of using its very helpful math environments. In this case you probably want the `equation` or (unnumbered) the `equation*` environment.

*(I also removed the preceding backslash `\` and moved it in front of `Delta`.)*

### Code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
%
l_{12} =  \frac {m_{c} c_{c} \frac {dT_{c}}{dt} + m_{s} c_{s} \frac {dT_{s}}{dt}}{m_{s}} \Delta t 
%
\]

\[
l_{12} =  \frac {m_{c} c_{c} \frac {dT_{c}}{dt} + m_{s} c_{s} \frac {dT_{s}}{dt}}{m_{s}} \Delta t 
\]

\begin{equation}
l_{12} =  \frac {m_{c} c_{c} \frac {dT_{c}}{dt} + m_{s} c_{s} \frac {dT_{s}}{dt}}{m_{s}} \Delta t 
\end{equation}

\begin{equation*}
l_{12} =  \frac {m_{c} c_{c} \frac {dT_{c}}{dt} + m_{s} c_{s} \frac {dT_{s}}{dt}}{m_{s}} \Delta t 
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image: Output]